# How to resolve this error ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, pycharm, python-3.6

I am getting below error while running setup.py install. How to resolve this issue?

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpn6r0j39bpycharm-management\setuptools-28.8.0\setup.py", line 11, in <module>
        import setuptools
      File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpn6r0j39bpycharm-management\setuptools-28.8.0\setuptools\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
        from setuptools.extern.six.moves import filter, filterfalse, map
      File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpn6r0j39bpycharm-management\setuptools-28.8.0\setuptools\extern\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
        from pkg_resources.extern import VendorImporter
      File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpn6r0j39bpycharm-management\setuptools-28.8.0\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
        import plistlib
      File "C:\Program Files\Python36-32\lib\plistlib.py", line 65, in <module>
        from xml.parsers.expat import ParserCreate
      File "C:\Program Files\Python36-32\lib\xml\parsers\expat.py", line 4, in <module>
        from pyexpat import *
    ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Comment: what package manager are you using?

Comment: @JasonStein Setuptools

Comment: it looks like you may be loading the wrong version of pyexpat.pyd (either wrong Python version or wrong architecture). I would start by checking your PYTHONPATH and PATH to make sure the first pyexpat.pyd your IDE/interpreter are encountering are the one from python 3.6